# Загрузка файла в переменную c++

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++, сокет

Везде искал, но так и не нашёл, как можно загрузить содержимое **http://site.ru/note.txt** в **переменную а не в файл.**  Там будет обычный текст. Вариант сохранять в файл а потом записать его в переменную - не подойдет. Может есть, допустим, аналог php-функции **file_get_contents**  
 Вот так:

```
URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"http://site.ru/note.txt", "path_to_save", 0, NULL);
```

Сохраняет только в файл, пробовал подставить заместо пути к файлу - переменную, не помогло.

Comment: Определяете (например, из http-заголовка) длину файла, выделяете память malloc-ом и читаете в эту память.

Если же в заголовке размера (Content-Length) нет, то придется делать цикл с realloc-ами (только вряд ли это будет эффективней, чем сохранить в файле, который потом mmap-нуть в память).

Само-собой результат malloc/realloc и будет той самой переменной с файлом.

А вообще-то способ хранения данных зависит от алгоритмов их дальнейшей обработки.

Comment: Если уж хотите пользоваться WinAPI, возьмите [`URLOpenStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и обрабатывайте нотификации о приходе данных.

Но я бы посоветовал писать портабельный код, и воспользоваться [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @VladD, libcurl универсально и удобно, и Вы сможете писать, куда захотите.